# Custom Type save decimal property only

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

We are on Entity Framework Core 2.0

I want to have a model that is using a Money type for one of its fields and is using a backing field that is of type decimal.

The goal is to get the backing field stored in the DB.

```
public class Order
    {
        private decimal _orderValue;

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Money OrderValue
        {
            get => new Money(_orderValue);
            set => _orderValue = value.Amount;
        }
    }
```

So the Money class is not an entity but used as a type. So we don't need Money to be in the DB at all. We do however want to store the backing decimal.
How can I go about making sure that EF creates and stores the _orderValue private field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I go about making sure that EF creates and stores the _orderValue private field?

You can rid of the backing field by better using EF Core 2.1 (which is in [Release Candidate 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-1-rc-1/) since 7 May 2018) you can use the feature of Value Conversion explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) by Microsoft:

> Value converters allow property values to be converted when reading
>   from or writing to the database. This conversion can be from one value
>   to another of the same type (for example, encrypting strings) or from
>   a value of one type to a value of another type (for example,
>   converting enum values to and from strings in the database.)

So for your case, you can just remove the backing field. You no longer need it. Your class should look like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Money OrderValue { get; set; }
}
```

And in your `OnModelCreating` method, you configure the conversion like below:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
    .Property(p => p.OrderValue)
    .HasConversion(
        v => v.Amount, // <- This is used when storing to the DB
        v => new Money(v) // <- this is used when reading data from your DB
    );
```

That's it. Actually it is in release candidate but Microsoft says:

> EF Core 2.1 RC1 is a “go live” release, which means once you test that
>   your application works correctly with RC1, you can use it in
>   production and obtain support from Microsoft, but you should still
>   update to the final stable release once it’s available.